# Make radio button at a particular position in grid view clicked

Tags: android, gridview, radio-button

I have a `recyclerview` and a `gridview` in one activity. On click of a radio button from recycler view I need the corresponding grid view radio button also to be checked and vice versa.. Please some one help me on this

Comment: add a interface and method to update data set in both the  adapters

Comment: can you explain it clearly

Comment: 1st - in ur data model add one more variable isradiochecked = false , add getter and setter for this variable
2nd - create a interface OnRedioselected with mtd onselected(int pos)
3rd - implement this interface in your activity 
4th - make a interface variable in both adapters constructor and pass activity instances to adapter and set it to local adapter instance
5th - make a method updateList() in both adapters 
6th - when radio selected in any adapter call OnRedioselected. onselected(pos)

Comment: 7th - in activity onselected mtd update the pos checked in your data list using set isradiochecked to true for that position and pass latest list in updateList() , PHEW..